# Using JSON without HTTPServlet?

Tags: jquery, json, http, servlets

So I have a simple html webpage that has a form. I want to send the form data as a JSON object to the jsp which will, in turn, use that data to query a database (this is an employee directory). Is there a way to do this without setting up the webapp as an HTTPServlet? If so, how can I do it? If not, is using the HTTPServlet methods as easy as just importing the HTTPServlet class?

The code I'm using to create the object in html is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").on("submit", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            var formData = JSON.stringify(jQuery("form").serializeArray());

            //console.log("Form Data: " + formData);
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Lack of information...Describe it more so that we can answer properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to submit form data (as JSON or not) for some server-side processing (in your case, query a database), you will have to set up your webapp with a HTTPServlet.

At the minimal, you will need the following.

An HTML form with its `method` attribute set to `post`, and its `action` set to the URL of the servlet:

```
<form name="login-form" method="post" action="LoginServlet">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"/> <br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

A Java HTTP servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
    }
}
```

If you have a `web.xml` file, make sure it uses the Servlet 3.0 spec:

```
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

Comment: Thanks. See updated question. Would formData need to be the variable I request?

Comment: Inside your `on-submit` function, you will need to make an ajax call when your `formData` as your `data` option. See the first example on this page http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @jordaniac89 Also, if you find this answer helpful, please mark it as accepted answer. Thanks :)